# Exploring heteroglossia in the semiotic novels of Umberto Eco

Tags: italian-language, umberto-eco, foucaults-pendulum, the-name-of-the-rose

Heteroglossia is an interesting and thoughtful literary term introduced by the Russian linguist Mikhail Bakhtin in his “Discourse in the Novel” in 1934. Heteroglossia describes the coexistence of varieties within a single “linguistic code”. Bakhtin argues that the power of the novel originates in the coexistence of, and conflict between, different types of speech: the speech of characters, the speech of narrators, and even the speech of the author.

Can we see the elements of heteroglossia in the novels with inter-textual references such as the works of Umberto Eco (*The Name of the Rose*, *Foucault's Pendulum*)?